# Grab Content from XML using Python? almost there

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I'm using ElementTree and I can get tags and attributes but not that actual content between elements.

from this XML:

```
<tag_name attrib="1">I WANT THIS INFO HERE</tag_name>
```

here's my python code:

```
import urllib2
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
XML = urllib2.urlopen("http://URL/file.xml")
Tree = ET.parse(XML)

for node in Tree.getiterator():
    print node.tag, node.attrib
```

This prints most of the XML file, and I understand what 'tag' and 'attrib' are, but how do I get the 'Content'? I tried looking through ElementTree's docs, but I think this might be too basic of a question.

Comment: What you mean by saying 'Content' ? I think that you are searching .text but Im not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***.text*** method should give you the required text value.

```
for node in Tree.getiterator():
    print node.tag, node.attrib, node.text
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try XPath ?

There are a lot of libraries to extract content from tags with a very easy yet powerful syntax.

Here an example:

```
import XmlXPathSelector
xs = XmlXPathSelector(text="<tags>your xml</tags>")
print xs.select("//tag_name[@attrib='1']/text()").extract()
```